# AG Grid Render React Component when a Cell is Clicked

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to render a React Component, which is basically a text box. I need to call onClick function only when any cell under "Age" column is clicked. The requirement is when the cell is clicked we need to render the React component.

Code section -
`cellRenderer: ClickableCellRenderer`

`function handleCellClicked(event){ if(event.colDef.field === "age") {<ClickableCellRender />}}`

This is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-hello-world-forked-5yxz28?file=/src/App.js:1316-1537

I am not able to link onClick with Cell Render, can anyone help here.

Comment: Can you please be specific about where the react component needs to be rendered on the cell click ? Anywhere outside the grid or at the same place where the cell is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to render the component on the cell itself on which you have clicked, `cellRenderer` in the `columnDefs` of the particular field is good to use.

`onCellClicked` can also work but it seems to be slow and is affecting the performance of application.

Here is the `gridOptions` declaration:-

```
   const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      {
        headerName: "ID",
        field: "id"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age",
        cellRenderer: ClickableCellRenderer
      }
    ],
    rowData 
 };
```

And in place of passing the state's setter and getter from `parent` component, I have declared the states inside `CellRenderer` Component. Hence the `CellRenderer` component will be rendering the component and also will handle the state for displaying the component on the basis of click.

```
   const ClickableCellRenderer = ({ value, data }) => {
  const [cellClicked, setCellClicked] = useState("");
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setCellClicked(data.id);
      }}
      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
    >
      {cellClicked ? <ClickableComponent value={value} /> : value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the full working [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-cellrenderer-87wj5z?file=/src/App.js:413-716).

Hope this provides any help.